# How to identify object according to the given scenario

Tags: javascript, json, oop

I created simple senario. The Initial requirement I want the projects to be listed and filtered.

1. lists all projects
2. filtered projects

here I want to identify the object that will be used in my solution according to the OOP concept.

JSON file

```
`{
    "projects": [
        { "id": 1, "name" : "Project 1" },
        { "id": 2, "name" :"Command 2" },
        { "id": 3, "name" :"Project 3" },
    ]
 }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function filterArr(arr, condition) {
    const res = []
    arr.forEach((item)=>{
        if(item === condition) {
            res.push(item)
        }
    })
    return res
}

function listArr(arr, order) {
    if(order === 0) {
        return arr
    }
    arr.sort((a, b) => {
        if(order == 1) {
            return a.id - b.id
        }
        if(order == -1) {
            return b.id - a.id
        }
    })
    return arr
}
```

Comment: Can you see if it works.

Comment: We are all new contributors. I need some reputation scores. If it is useful, can you vote up or accept the answer? Thank you.  Or we can improve each other's reputation score

Comment: as a questions I need answer for this question : Identify the object that will be used in your solution and justify the reasons for selecting these? like using OOP can you please explain this

Comment: This is based on the general meaning of your question (from my point of view). What is the relationship between OOP and JSON?

Comment: Actually this is a requirement analysing part. so I got only that json file. so then I just want to create simple UI using typescript/Js and HTML. but here I want to identify the objects that's the main task. because I want to create a class diagram for this also. ex project is one object like that how can we divide this project into separates part.

Comment: Then I think you can group projects according to the characteristics of this object